# Restrict some JS to work on specific websites

Tags: javascript, frontend

This is more of a conceptual question. I have a JS that I need to run when user is accessing only specific website(s). Is there any approach to make sure that my particular JS is invoked from some specific website(s)?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you control the websites in question? What approaches have you considered? What turns up in your research?

Comment: yes you can. do with browser extension https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: I do not, I was considering using 'window.location.href' but this can be emulated. I was considering arranging the JS to contact the mothership server to get an authorization code of some sort but i confess that  my front end knowledge is limited. Hence this question :) @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this if you:

1. Control the websites in question (in which case, just serve the code on those sites), or
2. Control/extend the *browser* being used. In this case, if you write a browser addon/extension, you can configure it to run when the browser goes to specific websites.

What you **can't** do is have website A (which you control) install JavaScript code that will run when a user (using a browser that doesn't have your addon/extension) goes to website B (which you don't) — for obvious security reasons. (Or rather, you can't do it without the user expressly chosing to by installing your addon/extension.)

Comment: Thank you. Option 1 us the most obvious of course that the arrangement that I have would allow 3rd party websites to serve the JS file in question. The trick is to prevent the use of this file by tinkerers who can easily grab and do what they want with it in a browser.

Comment: @RWS - You can't, full stop. You can make it slightly more difficult (by doing checks on `window.location.href`), but it's trivial to copy the code and remove the check (which is even easier than spoofing `window.location.href`). :-)

Comment: The spoofing of `window.location.href` was my main concern. But if preventing tinkering is not possible then it's not possible :)